# How do I configure the session in my cakephp application?

Tags: session, cakephp

Im trying create a endpoint for a session to my application. I follow all the steps in https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html
But dont works.

I create the table im my database called session and the ComboSession in src/Http/Session/ComboSession.php and change the conigurations in app.php like the documentation of cakephp suggests.

```
'Session' => [
    'defaults' => 'database',
    'handler' => [
        'engine' => 'ComboSession',
        'model' => 'session',
        'cache' => 'apc'
    ]
],
'Cache' => [
    'apc' => ['engine' => 'Apc']
]
```

I tried this too:

```
'Cache' => [
    'apc' => ['engine' => 'Apcu']
]
```

My error message: Cache engine Cake\Cache\Engine\ApcuEngine is not properly configured.

Comment: Your Cache configuration looks nothing like [what's documented](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html#configuring-cache-engines). The `engine` key is only for session configuration, the analogous thing in cache configuration is `className`.

Comment: Tank you for help Greg Schmidt. I change the configurations of cache to use defaults and works.

Answer (score 0):

My souluction:

```
'Session' => [
    'defaults' => 'database',
    'handler' => [
        'engine' => 'ComboSession',
        'model' => 'sessions',
        'cache' => 'defaults'
    ]
],

'Cache' => [
    'defaults' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Cache\Engine\FileEngine',
        'path' => CACHE,
        'url' => env('CACHE_DEFAULT_URL', null),
    ],
```